# Cannot play games with NVIDIA RTX 2070 Super + Intel Xeon Silver

Tags: steam, technical-issues, performance, graphics-card

For professional purposes, I work on a computer with the following specifications:

Graphics card **NVIDIA RTX 2070 SUPER (8 GB)**, Processor (x 2) Intel Xeon Silver 2.40 GHz, and 128 GB RAM

I tried to play Steam games on this PC, but I cannot make them work properly.
I tried with quite old games like Dying Light and Frostpunk → Impossible to play.
Briefly, I get one image every 5 sec. It is like playing 2020 games with a 2005 computer...

I really doubt my computer hasn't got the required specifications to play those games.
I "forced" the [games].exe to run on the RTX 2070 in the NVIDIA control panel as I thought it was not using it (all drivers up to date).

I monitored the use of my RTX 2070 while "playing" Dying Light  and the following appeared (sorry it is in French):

[image: Screenshot of the graphics card use)]

My graphics card does not seem to be used, or at least by "100% bursts".

I cannot figure out what is wrong here...
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Xeon processors tend to be in server hardware, in my experience. Are you asking a server to play these games?

Comment: what motherboard do you have in there?

Comment: Is your  monitor connected to the RTX2070 or maybe on an on-board graphics GPU?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a computer that is designed to be used as a server (judging by the processor and amount of RAM). While this is not ideal, the issues you are having sounds like you need to update your graphics driver. I would advise installing the driver through the NVIDIA website as well as doing any Windows Updates.